# Angular + Chrome Extension with content script

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension using angular (mostly for styling and routing). I know how to do communication between content and background scripts but the problem is, when I set variable in component X through chrome.runtime.onMessage, angular doesn't re-render. I tried using ChangeDetectorRef and manually triggering detect changes, but once I use that (which works), entire app becomes glitchy - for example, click over mat-select doesn't show anything unless I also add manual detectchange in mat-select onclick, mat-option onclick, etc. I don't want to use detectchange on every single thing which in my opinion is pointless + the whole "smooth" look is lost - like highlight animations and stuff like that.

I found something that angular can't detect changes which were made outside of angular's control, but is there a workaround / fix for all of this or not?

I expected every variable change in any component to automatically detect changes which were made from chrome.runtime.onMessage listener. I tried using ChangeDetectorRef but it breaks other normal behavior.

Comment: It is possible to see the code ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a solution to this, I'll post my solution which is pretty ugly but works like a charm.
I made additional 'tmp' variables which are set on chrome.runtime.onMessage, then I added loops using setInterval in my ngOnInit to compare actual and tmp variables and set the 'original' ones to tmp if they are not equal. I know it's not the perfect solution but for small amount of variables with decent loop timers, it's more then decent performance.